# Does setting a ThreadLocal variable in a constructor work?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning java Threads , i go to the lesson about local thread values and I decided to make a program that uses them.
I set the local thread value in constructor(the thread constructor) show it on screen to check that it worked but when I start the threads the local values turn to NULL so I get NullPointerException.
Did i miss something , or I can only set the local thread values in the start method ?

```
package practice;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Try
{   
    Thread a1,a2,a3;
    int x=0;
    synchronized void change(int who){
        out.println("who called"+who);
        out.println("x initial="+x);
        x++;
        out.println("x after="+x);
    }
    class now implements Runnable{
        ThreadLocal<Integer> id=new ThreadLocal<Integer>();
        public void run(){
            for(int i=1;i<=25;i++){
            out.println("im running id="+id.get());
            change(id.get());
            out.println("after call me="+id.get());
            }
        }
        now(int givenid){
            out.println("my givenid is "+givenid);
            id.set(givenid);
            out.println("my id is "+id.get());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        new Try();
    }


    Try(){

    a1=new Thread(new now(1));
    a2=new Thread(new now(2));
    a1.start();
    a2.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: where have u used set() or initialValue() method of threadLocal to initialize threadlocal?

Comment: Don't say "ThreadLocal _variable_".  While it's true that you have a variable, and its type is `ThreadLocal<Integer>`, the thread local-ness is not a property of the variable; It's a property of the _object_ to which the variable refers.  A ThreadLocal _object_ is an object with get() and set() methods that refer to different locations depending on which thread calls them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the Banthar's answer, but I just want to illustrate what happens with your code by adding just a few prints...

```
package threads;

import static java.lang.System.out;

class Main {
    Thread a1, a2, a3;
    int x = 0;

    public Main() {
        out.println("Current thread (in Main's constructor): " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        a1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(1));
        a2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(2));
        a1.start();
        a2.start();
    }

    private synchronized void change(int who) {
        out.println("Current thread (in change() method): " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        out.println("who called" + who);
        out.println("x initial=" + x);
        x++;
        out.println("x after=" + x);
    }

    private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        ThreadLocal<Integer> id = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();

        public MyRunnable(int givenid) {
            out.println("Current thread (in MyRunnable's constructor): " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            out.println("my givenid is " + givenid);
            id.set(givenid);
            out.println("my id is " + id.get());
        }

        public void run() {
            out.println("Current thread (in run() method): " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            out.println("im running id=" + id.get());
            change(id.get());
            out.println("after call me=" + id.get());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Current thread (in Main's constructor): main
Current thread (in MyRunnable's constructor): main
my givenid is 1
my id is 1
Current thread (in MyRunnable's constructor): main
my givenid is 2
my id is 2
Current thread (in run() method): Thread-0
Current thread (in run() method): Thread-1
im running id=null
im running id=null
```

Sorry for changing the names a bit.

As you can see when instantiating `MyRunnable` (yours `now` class) you set the `ThreadLocal` in the **main** thread. That's why you cannot access it via the other threads.

Answer (score 1):

This is how thread locals are supposed to work. Thread local is like a map from thread to object. Every thread sees it's own value. You are setting the value in main thread and only that thread will see this value.

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here. Thread locals are usually used to cache non thread safe objects, which are expensive to allocate and it's not feasible to pass them via argument. They will usually be stored in static field. For example:

```
private static ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> FORMAT = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>();

public static Date parse(final String date) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = FORMAT.get();
    if (format == null) {
        format = new SimpleDateFormat();
        FORMAT.set(format);
    }
    return format.parse(date);
}
```

This will cache one instance of `SimpleDateFormat` per thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the "wrapped" value inside the `ThreadLocal`. Take a look at the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). You'll need to call either `set()` or use `initialValue()` before your `ThreadLocal` will return anything but `null`.